# Split a string into multiple lines

Tags: java, string, split, jsoup

I have a program that gets the stats of hockey players on a specific team using Jsoup and puts it in to a single string. I want to split the lines up so I can get the stats for each player in their own string. This is the code I have and explained:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://espn.go.com/nhl/team/stats/_/name/phi/philadelphia-flyers").get();

    for (Element table : doc.select("table.tablehead")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
             if (tds.size() > 6) {
                String a = tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text() + " GOALS: " + tds.get(2).text() + " ASSISTS: " + tds.get(3).text() + " POINTS: " + tds.get(4).text() + " PLUS/MINUS: " + tds.get(5).text() + " PIM: " + tds.get(6).text();
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output gives multiple lines, to give you an idea these are the first three lines it gives:

```
PLAYER:GP GOALS: G ASSISTS: A POINTS: PTS PLUS/MINUS: +/- PIM: PIM
Matt Read, C:13 GOALS: 5 ASSISTS: 4 POINTS: 9 PLUS/MINUS: 2 PIM: 2
Brayden Schenn, C:12 GOALS: 2 ASSISTS: 6 POINTS: 8 PLUS/MINUS: 3 PIM: 5
```

If the beginning of the line = Matt Read I want to make a string that contains:

```
Matt Read, C:13 GOALS: 5 ASSISTS: 4 POINTS: 9 PLUS/MINUS: 2 PIM: 2
```

If the beginning of the line = Brayden Schenn I want to make a string that contains:

```
Brayden Schenn, C:12 GOALS: 2 ASSISTS: 6 POINTS: 8 PLUS/MINUS: 3 PIM: 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm not understanding the code, you seem to pretty much already do this - each line is in the `String a` variable on every loop iteration.  You just need to  save outward each assignment of `a`.  Instantiate an `ArrayList<String>` prior to your initial for loop and add variable `a` to it prior to your call to `System.out.println(a);`.  After you exit your for loop, your `ArrayList` should contain each appropriate individual `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // THIS LINE IS NEW

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://espn.go.com/nhl/team/stats/_/name/phi/philadelphia-flyers").get();

    for (Element table : doc.select("table.tablehead")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
             if (tds.size() > 6) {
                String a = tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text() + " GOALS: " + tds.get(2).text() + " ASSISTS: " + tds.get(3).text() + " POINTS: " + tds.get(4).text() + " PLUS/MINUS: " + tds.get(5).text() + " PIM: " + tds.get(6).text();

                    list.add(a);  // THIS LINE IS NEW

                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }

        // at this point, variable "list" contains each String assigned to "a" above.

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Scanner class to pull individual lines out of any body of text (or directly from the file) by calling the scanner.nextLine() method.  It will just scan through the input string until it encounters a new line character, and return everything up to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a scanner, or more preferably a List, or even a HashMap to store the information about the player in.

Instead of printing the line, declare your prefered type and store the string a there.